# The use of the preposition "po"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I still don't get the meaning of the preposition *po*

Could you give me some examples where it is used ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That preposition could have been taken from Bulgarian, which has the same preposition:

- *Po kvar personoj sidas ĉe la (3) tabloj.*

Every time 4 persons sit at the (3) tables = 12 persons.
4 Persons are sitting at each table.

I have taken this weird example by choice: *po* here functions more like an adverb, and even Zamenhof also used the accusative with *po*.

There is a corresponding *per* in English - at the other place.
So *po* means *each time, by*. German has *jeweils*, Dutch *telkens*.

It expresses a quantitative unit repeated: each time.

- *La intervjuoj prenis po du personoj en ĉiuj ĉambroj.*
  The interviews *each* took two persons in every room.
- *Ŝi veturis po ducent kilometrojn en horo.*
  She drove two hundred kilometres per hour.

In fact, one could (semantically) combine *po* with a preposition:

*La intervjuoj okazis kun po du personoj en ĉiuj ĉambroj.*
    The interviews happened with two persons each in the rooms / per room.

I would personally see it as an **adverb** before a numeral.

Comment: I'm not sure whether *po* came from Bulgarian or some other Slavic language (maybe Zamenhof's native Polish has such) but it is true that in Bulgarian it is exactly the same word and used with the same rules. Being a native Bulgarian speaker, *„po“* feels intuitive to me, and I think *everytime* is not a perfect translation, as *po* is not related to time, only to quantity. I would translate your example of *Po kvar personoj…* as *On each table, there are 4 people*. Conicidentally, *po* in Bulgarian is used for multiplication too: *3 по 4 = 12* Also, isn't that *ĉiu ĉambro* (singular)?

Comment: The Lyubomir's description is also valid for the Russian language.

Comment: Regarding *po* as an adverb before numerals, other prepositions have this kind of thing as well: *Mi havas ĉirkaŭ cent pomojn*. Here *ĉirkaŭ* describes just *cent* rather than the entire direct object.